# Why is it a present sense in the sub-clause, not the same past tense as in main-clause?

Tags: tense

> American Airlines confirmed that it would slash 19,000 jobs in October, **when the requirement to retain staff ends under the conditions of the federal bail-out of the aviation industry.** The government was said to be considering a new rescue package for America’s biggest airlines.

---

Why is it a present sense in the subordinate clause, not the same past tense as in main clause? Is it because "when" equal to "if" thus the sense do not have to in accordance with main clause?

Comment: When the situation referred to in a subordinate clause is still current, English speakers often use the present rather than the past; eg _Did you know that Jane was/is a doctor?_  - both are idiomatic. In this case, where the action of the subordinate clause is in the future, the past, though possible, would be confusing (did they mean this October or last?), and I think the present is much more natural.

Comment: Thank you. I thought tense represents the time when exactly the action happens, and since it "end", it ended, that's why I asked.

Comment: Hi, wtdark. It's a **huge** oversimplification to say "tense represents the time when exacetly the action happens". But here, the time when the "requirement to retain staff ends" is in the future: it is now only just September, not October.